# Selenium 2 : Android drivers installation - Jetty not get started and in localhost wd hub not found

Tags: android-emulator, selenium-webdriver, ijetty

My aim is to run tests in android emulator using selenium2 downloading android drivers
Followed the same steps mentioned in the http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver
a) JDK / JRE installed
b) Android SDK (windows) is there 
c) Created AVD and got the 3.2 version OS target from the SDK manager
d) Started the emulator and installed the selenium android server in the emulator ( installed webdriver APK )
e) Got Selenium standalone server installed 127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html ( displayed sessions )

f) Done the port forwarding adb -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
g) Ran this command adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity
h) My webdriver started displayed - Webdriver ready

But the issue is Jetty not get started ( not displayed in emulator as Jetty started )

And the android server not  available at localhost:8080/wd/hub from the host machine. ( tried using ipaddress also .. no joy )

When I ran my test by changing to driver = new AndroidDriver();

Failure: SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error.

Error 404 Not Found

HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /hub/session. Reason:
    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone help why this is happening ? and solution for the same

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Be sure in the AVD you set up your emulator to have an SDCARD with a nonzero size. Selenium appears to require an SDCARD to write temporary data, and the server will silently fail when you try to create a driver, causing what appears to be on the end user to be a 404 or similar error.